# WiX: Invalid Language Id

Tags: installation, wix

Some executable files have resources marked "language neutral".

Is it possible to package these binaries using WiX?

The error I receive is: error LGHT0204 : ICE03: Invalid Language Id; Table: File, Column: Language, Key(s)

Setting the Product.Language attribute to '0' does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the retrieval of file information by passing this option to light.exe:

> `-sh`
>   Suppress file information: do not get hash, version, language and
>   other file properties

To fix the original cause of the error, compare the incorrect language ID to the ones [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you verify that the Language Id is truly valid (I've never seen a case where the ICE was wrong though) then I would suppress the ICE before suppressing the hash information (-sh). The hash information is very important for your install. Instead use "light.exe -sice ICE03" to skip that ICE.

Also note that the ICE03 checks are pretty important so make sure you solve all the other issues befor supressing this it. There is a feature request out there to suppress only specific errors instead of the whole ICE.

Comment: Is there a way to define the language as a variable in wix to use in Product tag?

Comment: For me preprocessor is not working. because i am declaring the variable inside the product tag